# CSS Div positioning in Table

Tags: css, html-table

I have tried all sorts of combinations, but nothing seems to work.

I have a table with three cells.  Each cell contains a div with a set width.  The left block tends to run vertically very long, but now I need the center and right div blocks to also stretch to the length of the table.  (Unfortunately I can't remove the table, since it is set into the code of system I am using).

I have made a simple recreation of the layout.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<title>layout test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style>
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#contentBlock {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#contentBlock .leftBlock {
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
}
#contentBlock .rightBlock {
        background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
}
#contentBlock .centerBlock {
    background-color: red;
    width: 580px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<table width="1000" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="background-color: #e2e2e2;">
    <div id="contentBlock">
        <table width="980" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="200" valign="top"><div class="leftBlock">
              <p>left block</p>
              <p>sdf</p>
              <p>sdf</p>
              <p>sdf</p>
              <p>sdf</p>
              <p>sdf</p>
            </div></td>
            <td width="580" valign="top"><div class="centerBlock">
              <p>centerBlock</p>
              <p>dfg</p>
            </div></td>
            <td width="200" valign="top"><div class="rightBlock">
              <p>rightBl</p>
              <p>ock</p>
            </div></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div></td>
  </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: give the divs a height of 100%

Comment: Mikey, that won't work. It will extend to the height of its content

Comment: Are you using tables for layout? What is the purpose of the outer table? That makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just move the `background-color` to the `td's` instead of the div?

```
#contentBlock td {
 background-color: red; 
}
```

Comment: It seems I made a typo in my fighting with this CSS :(  The Div is a little bit smaller than the TD,  <td width="200">  <div width="180">.  The idea is to have a bit of space on each side of the Div.

Comment: Just add padding on the `td` then to give it "space"

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you can do this is with javascript. CSS does not offer a way to extend vertical heights other than using the height/min-height properties.

Comment: With jQuery it would be very easy: $('.centerblock, .rightblock').css('height', heightVal); and make sure you set heightval to be the css height of leftblock.

Comment: heightVal = $('.leftblock').css('height');